# How can I publish a nodJS app on aws?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, server, upload

[image]

I'm using a free tier version of aws cloud, and have some trouble with loading up a nodeJs Application. I 've tried to follow the documentation of aws but it didn't work unfortunately. I choose the Elastic BeanStalk, from the services, and create a new Application. I choose nodeJs for the preconfigured platform of course. I make a zip with my app, and I really pay attention, to not have any parent folder above package.json, and app.js . As you can see on the picture above, I have a folder "public" which contains additional folders (css,img, javascript code). When I try to upload the project, I get an error message.
"Failed to find package.json. Node.js may have issues starting. Verify package.json is valid or place code in a file named server.js or app.js." In the project view I've got a health status "degraded", and an other error code:      "i-045ac359227e3a9ae"   Severe
I 've tried many php projects on this server, and everything worked fine,but I can't make it work with Node. Could you help me out please?

package.json:

```
 {
  "name": "kutyapplikacio",

  "version": "1.0.0",

  "description": "Egy alkalmazás kutyáknak és gazdáiknak",

  "main": "server.js",

  "scripts": {
    "test": "test",

    "start": "node server.js"
  },

 "author": "sethdevelop",

 "license": "ISC",

 "dependencies": {

"body-parser": "^1.17.2",

"express": "^4.15.3",

"express-mailer": "^0.3.1",

"express-mysql": "0.0.1",

"express-validator": "^3.2.0",

"mysql": "^2.13.0",

"nodemailer": "^4.0.1",

"nodemailer-smtp-transport": "^2.7.4"
```

}
}

Comment: What is inside the `package.json`? Also it could be the method you are using to zip the files, when you zip you may be nesting your things inside their current folder, so when elastic beanstalk unzips it nothing is in the directory where it unzips except for the folder containing your things.

Comment: I updated the post. The zipping method: I mark out the files, right click, zip, add to zip file

Comment: Compare the structure of your ZIP file to the AWS example at https://github.com/awslabs/eb-node-express-sample/releases/download/v1.1/eb-node-express-sample-v1.1.zip.

Comment: I uploaded this example project, and it works. So it has to be my app strucutre

Comment: This is how I did it without beanstalk and manually configured the EC2 instance https://medium.com/@adhasmana/how-to-quickly-deploy-react-and-node-app-on-aws-80e5dfe7d86e

Comment: Are you zipping the project folder or it's content. ?

Comment: Only the content. I pay attention not to include the project folder.

Answer (score 0):

The error message you wrote is :  "Failed to find package.json. Node.js may have issues starting. Verify package.json is valid or place code in a file named server.js or app.js."

From the folder I only see you have app.js file.

And in your package.json, there are server.js:

```
"main": "server.js",    
  "scripts": {
    "test": "test",    
    "start": "node server.js"
  }
```

Perhaps you should change server.js to app.js ?

---

Update

Since you mentioned they have the same name:
could it be you zipped the folder instead of zipped the files ?
Same problem has been discussed here:
https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=477087
https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=130140

Comment: I thought the name could be the problem, so I renamed it, and forgot to make it back. But when I uploaded the zip, everything had proper name.

Comment: Could you tell us which document you were reading ? Like this one : http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/nodejs-getstarted.html ?

Comment: I followed exactly this documentation. Whatever I do, i get an 502 bad gateway, when I try to launch the app link.

Comment: I tried to really attentively make the zip file. I appoint the files, and make the zip file, without any parent folder, I'm sure about it.